# Can I plug my amp directly into my audio interface?

Tags: guitar, amplifiers

Could anyone tell me, can I plug my guitar amp directly into my audio interface (with the "line out")?
On some forums people say that you can't , on others people say you can...

If it's possible, is there things you shouldn't do to avoid any damage to the interface? (I saw somewhere you had to have the loudspeakers hooked up when you are recording... why is that ?)

Answer (score 12):

If the output jack is labeled `line out` it means it can be plugged into any line-level input, as those found in audio interfaces, so you should be safe.

If your interface is "pro" grade, it can have Mic inputs and "Hi-Z" (or Instrument) inputs too, so check if it's the case and make sure you plug into the *line* inputs.

Also, keep in mind that unless the "line out" has *speaker emulation* (and a good one, too!), you probably won't like the sound you'll get.

As for the speaker, it should **always** be connectd (expecially if it's a tube amplifier) unless you wanna risk damaging the amp. Amplifier transformers need the correct load to work properly and within safe parameters.

If the volume is too much for where you're playing (and that's why you're asking about the speaker connection), you can buy an [attenuator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_attenuator_(guitar)), which gives you lower volume while keeping the right load on the amplifier transformers.
Some models have an emulated line out which is usually better than the stock one if you want to use it for recordings.

Comment: If line out doesn't have speaker simulation you can use the simulator of your choosing, from basic eq'ing to free VSTs to extremely expensive premium VSTs. OTOH, if it does, it probably sucks and you are stuck with a crappy sound. I had better results by clumsily miking up my VOX Valvetronix with a $9 computer mic (in fact I got a nice sound) than I had with its, ugh, "line out".

Answer (score 3):

If your amp has  a "line out" or headphones jack, then you should be able to connect that to the audio interface.  Note that usually this means that the output is low impedendence, and the amount of pre amp gain that you'll need is lower than you'd need for plugging the guitar straight in (the amplifier is providing some initial amplification).

The same holds true for the output (send) from an effects loop, the signal has been pre amplified to (approximately) line level.  Note that you would need to complete the loop in this case; basically I'm saying that you should be able to put the interface into an effects loop. If I were doing this though,
I'd start the pre-amp gain as low as possible before plugging into the interface, since this is not commonly done.

However *do not* plug speaker output(s) into the inputs of an audio interface -- this will surely break the amp or the interface (or both).

Comment: "However do not plug speaker output(s) into the inputs of an audio interface -- this will surely break the amp or the interface (or both)." Man, i did this one night, maybe i was luck, but my gear is fine to this day, however no one should try this at home! hahaha

Answer (score 1):

You can but the sound will not be quite the same as if you record the sound of the amp with a microphone, you are loosing all the amp characteristics like, the sound of the cabinet, the extrusion of the speaker and even perhaps the feedback it gives to the guitar (like when you put your guitar close to the amp to cause an intentional feedback loop),  but you can do it and always is a good choice if you don't want or can put a mic in front of it. Even if it only have headphone out can be done although its not the most optimal option.